# How to arrange the sequence of the order while Viewing the Clustered Column Chart based on the slicer in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have created a Clustered Column chart with four columns in X-Axis and 4 columns in Y-Axis, I'm using the same four columns from X-Axis as slicer.

Here is the output I'm getting :
[Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9CUl.png)

**Expecting Output**: I want the data of "Type" to displayed first and then based on the other slicer filters the remaining should be displayed based on "Primary Classification", "Secondary Classification" & "Element" in sequential order.
this should be the landing page:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ2b9.png)

What I have Tried :

1. I have tried to rearrange the order of the selection on X-Axis but no use.
2. One more possible way which I have tried to remove the default functionality when a slicer is selected which pulls the data of all the rows, but Power BI does not allow to change.